# How do I get tox to use interpreters installed by pyenv when using tox installed via pipx?

Tags: python, pyenv, tox, pipx

I installed tox globally via [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) as follows:

```bash
pipx install tox
tox --version
4.6.4
```

I have installed Python 3.10 via [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) as follows:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10.12
```

However, when I run `tox` with a `py310` environment, I get the following error message:

```
skipped because could not find python interpreter with spec(s): py310
```

How can I get tox (installed via pipx) to recognise the versions of Python I installed via pyenv?

Comment: Note that this message may be misleading because it also shows up for problems otherwise related to building your package. For example, I saw this because of a syntax error in my setup.cfg. The crucial thing for me was to study the stack traces and error messages in the output above; for me they showed up as indented blocks of red print.

Answer (score 3):

I went through a few iterations before I found a solution. First of all I found the [tox-pyenv](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-pyenv) plugin but it turns out that the plugin has been deprecated since tox 4.

I tried setting the `VIRTUALENV_DISCOVERY` environment variable recommended in the README of the tox-pyenv plugin but then `tox` threw a bunch of exceptions.

So in the end I configured all required versions in my project directory via `pyenv local 3.10.12 3.11.4` and now tox runs just fine.

I hope this helps someone else!

PS. If you really want to use `tox-pyenv` with tox 3.x, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715740/722553). If you've installed tox via pipx, try the [pipx inject](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/docs/#pipx-inject) command to install `tox-pyenv` into the same pipx environment where `tox` is installed.

Comment: I failed to reproduce this using pyenv-win and Windows. The tox 3 approach did work though.

Comment: The `virtualenv-pyenv` plugin author is here. As stated in the README of the `tox-pyenv` plugin, `VIRTUALENV_DISCOVERY=pyenv` instructs `virtualenv` to use the `virtualenv-pyenv` discovery mechanism; therefore, `virtualenv-pyenv` must be installed alongside `tox`. Since it requires an additional configuration step, which seems to confuse inexperienced users, I've updated my `tox-pyenv-redux` (not related to `tox-pyenv`) plugin to support tox 4. It uses `virtualenv-pyenv` under the hood. https://github.com/un-def/tox-pyenv-redux Just install it instead of `tox-pyenv`, it should "just work"

Comment: @dawngerpony I'm so confused.  I keep reading about how using `pyenv local` with mulitple versions of python fixes the use of tox.  I have never set that and yet my tox automatically picks up py38, py39, py311.  I can't seem to find documentation to help me understand why mine is working.